# what is a transport

Tags: integration, wso2-esb

lets say there's a already implemented messaging protocol connector.Which enable us to send the message with various scenarios like , (No encryption, no signature ),(No encryption, signature) ,(Encryption, no signature), (MDN over HTTP, no signature),( MDN over HTTP, signature) etc don't we have to handle those scenarios within the custom transport we wrote for wso2Esb ? and can we integrate those connectors with the transport and extract the message out of it ? Is it the normal way of doing it? Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using a transport in very high level you transfer the incoming message / information to a XML info set and then pass it to processing engine.Inside ESB we only process XML messages therefore inside the transport Listner we convert the incoming message to that common XML info set SOAP and then inject to processing engine. In the Transport Sender we convert back into the Sender Transports Message model or protocol.
For some advance use cases like you have mentioned you can refer FIX transport [1] as an starting point.

Refer this [2] for complete Transport catalog which will give you an understanding of how such similar transports are available.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/3837#fix_implementation

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/WSO2+Carbon+Transports